# Use vba selenium to choose option from drop menu

Tags: vba, selenium, class, web-scraping, html-lists

PLS help me with vba selenium code.
There is drop menu (name Select Bookmark)
inside there is list with three option, i need to choose third option.

Tried to use some code from other solution but without success.

```
<ul id="aaa" class="bbb"> == $0
    ::before
    <li class="ccc">
        ::before
        <select>
            <option value>Select Bookmark</option>
            <option value="Server\BHG-145">bookmark_one</option>
            <option value="Server\BHG-155">bookmark_two</option>
            <option value="Server\BHG-165">bookmark_three</option>
        </select>
        ::after
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you add the selenium you are currently using?

Comment: you should really include your current code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an attribute = value selector

```
driver.FindElementByCss("[value='Server\BHG-165']").selected = True
driver.FindElementByCss("[value='Server\BHG-165']").click
```

or select by index

```
driver.FindElementByCss(".ccc select").AsSelect.SelectByIndex 3
```

or by text

```
driver.FindElementByCss(".ccc select").AsSelect.SelectByText "bookmark_three"
```